# CRM online Report not updating?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-online

I have a problem where after a weekly activity report is run, there could be updates to an activity. But after the report has been run again the update information is not shown on the report.

I have created the reports in report wizard.

My filter criteria:

```
Activities 
        Activity Status Equals Completed;Open;Scheduled
AND     Start Date Last Week

Customers
    Modified On Last X Days 30
```

I have tried

1. Clearing the filtered criteria.
2. Deleting the report.
3. Re-uploading the report.
4. Refreshing the Webpage.

Could this be something on the Report Server Side?

Like clearing the cache?

How would I clear the cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you say the updated information isn't shown on the report, you're saying that it only displays the original information at all times?

It depends on what browser you are using to clear your cache, but this site makes it pretty easy to figure it out. [Refresh Your Cache](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/)

Comment: Thanks, for that handy link , i have tried that  put the old data is still displaying.

Comment: Do you have other reports that are working? Just trying to eliminate the Server Side problem...

Comment: Hi Joel, yes i have ran other reports and they are fine.I have done an iisreset on the report server too.